# NodeJS - Google search API isn't returning anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-search

I'm using NodeJS and I'm trying to perform a Google search.

I'm using the [google package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google). Here is my code:

```
const google = require('google');
google.resultsPerPage = 25;

        google('wikipedia', function (err, res) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
            console.log(res.links);
        });
```

And `res.links` is an empty array. I made the search manually, with the exact link used by the node app (which is https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=wikipedia&start=0&sa=N&num=25&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl), and I get results.

Do you have any idea why it's not returning anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You have a syntax error

It should be

```
const google = require('google');

google.resultsPerPage = 25;

google('wikipedia', function (err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
        console.log(res.links);
    }
});
```

Second, if you check the package's Github page, it seems that the it does not work anymore https://github.com/jprichardson/node-google/issues/65 and they are suggesting using https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-it instead.

Comment: be nice to point out where is the syntax error.

Comment: thanks. indeed I removed useless code and I forgot to fix that error, thank you.

Comment: @Ituriel no worries! If this answered your question please consider marking it as the accepted answer!